# How to correctly align fixed header fully to top and left in CSS

Tags: html, css, header, alignment

So I have come across a problem when I tried aligning my header design fully to the top margin and the left margin. The use HTML and CSS to perform this.
CSS code:

```
div#headerbox
{
background-color: #a56868;
width:100%;
height: 40px;
position: fixed;
display: block;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
}

div#headerwrap
{
background-color: #a56868;
width:100%;
height: 40px;
position: fixed;
display: block;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="headerbox">
    <div id="headerwrap">
        <p>TEST 123</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Why doesnt this code align properly to the edges on both sides as I have put the lenght of the element to be 100%? and how can I fix this?

[image: Current look]

Comment: Have you made sure that none of your container elements have a margin? Some browser seem to add one automatically to `<body>`

Comment: The body did not have a given value, and that is probably why the browser added a some margin automatically. Fixed using the margin: 0; and padding 0; in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the padding and margin of HTML body in CSS to zero.

```
body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mention

```
*{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

in you css file

this will prevent default padding and margin of all block elements.

Answer (score 0):

Apply style margin:0; to the body element.

```
body{
   margin:0;
}
```

For more information on margin property you can check out this page:
http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-reference/css-margin-property.php

Answer (score 0):

- {margin:0px; padding:0px;}
  body, html {margin:0px; padding:0px;}

Mention this code is css to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
body {    margin: 0;    padding: 0; }
```

For more information [How to correctly align fixed header fully to top and left in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160707/how-to-correctly-align-fixed-header-fully-to-top-and-left-in-css)

Comment: Edited to not use knockoff site